# Copying VBoxAdditions to usr/share/virtualbox folder

Tags: 11.10, virtualbox

Since for some reason VBox does not find the Additions on the internet, I was trying to install them in the Ubuntu directory Vbox is looking for them - which is:

usr/share/virtualbox

but I am denied permission to do so. Any way around it? I am relatively new to ubuntu (know how to use the GUI, but still learning how to talk to the machine proper, so many things will be new to me; used to be power user/analyst for MS Windows, 98-Vista, so not a PC newbie, but still I'd say Linux newbie).

Any suggestion is more than welcome!
Thanks
Joe

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Open terminal and type in `gksu nautilus` and hit enter.  It might ask you to enter your password.

Browse to `usr/share/virtualbox` and copy the Virtual Box Guest addtion iso to the folder